# MySQL and C# Entity Framework "ProviderIncompatibleException"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i'm following the MySql tutorial to entity framework as listed here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

I have installed in my project via NuGet:
- Entity Framework v6.2.0
- MySql.Data.Entity v6.10.7

And their corresponding dependencies.

I have installed the MySql CONNECTOR/NET v8.0.11.

I added the provider and connectionString to the App.config:

```
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mysql" connectionString="Server=localhost,3306;Database=eneagramas;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Basically i followed all the instructions in the official documentation, this is my context class:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("mysql")
    {
        //nothing here
    }

    public DbSet<Humans> Humans { get; set; }
}
```

YET i get this error when accesing the DB:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:[...]

Inner Exception 1:
MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' to access method 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Settings()' failed.
```

- I checked my DB credentials, they are fine
- The server is up and running
- The database im trying to use exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) 8.0.11 with [MySql.Data.Entity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/) 6.10.7; the major versions are incompatible.

Oracle [renamed the package](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,661134) to [MySql.Data.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework) for v8. Uninstall MySql.Data.Entity and install MySql.Data.EntityFramework instead.

Comment: I did that, and also changed this line:
    <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">

to this:
    <entityFramework>

Problem solved, thanks.